# WP Power Builder не работает

Tags: wordpress

Не работает Power Builder не вносит изменения в блоки. У меня установлена версия Power Builder Version 1.3.0 и Вордпресса 5.5. Когда я захожу чтобы редактировать страницу и нажимаю на значок настройки в блоке PowerBuilder ничего не происходит. Сайт был создан три года назад, сейчас необходимо внести некоторые изменения.Что делать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поясните, как именно он не работает. Что вы делали, в каком месте не получилось. Поскольку вы новый участник, вы еще не знаете, что нужно как можно более подробно описывать свои проблемы. Мы не видим вашу проблему и не можем догадаться, что именно у вас не получилось. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос.

Comment: У меня установлена версия Power Builder Version 1.3.0 и Вордпресса 5.5. Когда я захожу чтобы редактировать страницу и нажимаю на значок настройки в блоке PowerBuilder ничего не происходит. Сайт был создан три года назад, сейчас необходимо внести некоторые изменения

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, вам нужен [jQuery Migrate Helper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enable-jquery-migrate-helper/) плагин.

После обновления WordPress до версии 5.5 перестают работать старые скрипты.

Comment: +1 :) *и ещё кучка ненужных символов.*

Comment: @SeVlad 

Answer (score 0):

Есть аналогичная проблема вот здесь:

https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-power-builder/

Решили ее так:

> связался с саппортом вопрос решен путем установления
> https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/ Power Builder заработал
> снова

То есть, если установить плагин Classic Editor по ссылке, ваш Power Builder может снова заработать. Попробуйте.

Вообще проблема состоит в том, что у вас обновился WordPress, а этот самый Power Builder (скорее всего, о нем мало кто знает) не обновляется и теряет совместимость с современными платформами. И в перспективе, чтобы не было проблем с Power Builder, рано или поздно от него придется отказаться.

Comment: Да, я пробовала этот вариант и не помогло. Даже попробовала установить disable gutenberg и тоже ничего. Думаю может просто отмотать более старую версию вордпреса

Comment: Я обновил ответ. Возможно, вы предпочтете отказаться от PowerBuilder, потому что WordPress все равно приходится обновлять.